# change propetries of command button on form navigation in access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an access form having  a command button which will perform  a certain action onclick for the current record.
I need to disable the button function by navigating the records before the current one from the form or in other words, to have the button property (enabled) = false all the time except when the current record is new only.

this makes me thinking on how to inform access vba to navigate and if the current record is a new one, then to enable the button to perform its function, or if it is one preivouse record then to nake the button property (enabled) = false.

Can this be performed and works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the form's `NewRecord` property from code for the On Current event, and use that to enable/disable your command button.

So, if the command button is named "cmdFoo":

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Me.NewRecord = True Then
        Me.cmdFoo.Enabled = True
    Else
        Me.cmdFoo.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

However, this way is more concise.  Use the approach which seems clearer to you.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.cmdFoo.Enabled = Me.NewRecord
End Sub
```